# Calculate percentage of total columns based on total column in SSRS Matrix

Tags: matrix, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Looking to add a column in my SSRS Matrix which will give me the percentage from the total column in that row.

I'm using the following expression, but keep getting 100% for my percentages (I'm assuming this is because the total is evaluated last, so it's just doing Total/Total?

```
=FORMAT((Fields!ID.Value/SUM(Fields!ID.Value)), "P")
```

The field ID is calcuted within SQL, not SSRS.

For example

```
Site   |  Value 1  |    %1   |   Value2  |   %2    |   Total
  1    |    20     |   50%   |    20     |   50%   |    40
```

Comment: Are the values of "Value 1" and "Value 2" the same for example purposes or are they being fed by the same Fields!ID.Value?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Probably this is happening because you need define the right scope for the SUM function:

`SUM(Fields!ID.Value,"group_name")` instead of plain `SUM(Fields!ID.Value)`

Updated:

I needed some time to make an example since I didn't have reporting services available the first time I answered you.

You can see the result and the field values

[image]

[image]

Comment: This seems like it should be the correct sollution; however, when you add a totals column, it does not get assigned a group name.  This makes it not callable.

Answer (score 8):

Hard to provide details without more info on the setup of your groups, but you should look at using the scope option to the aggregate operators like SUM or first:

```
=SUM(Fields!ID.Value, "NameOfRowGrouping") / SUM(Fields!ID.Value, "TopLevelGroupName")
```

Also, to keep things clean, you should move your format out of the expression and to either the placeholder properties or textbox properties that contains your value.

Comment: Thanks - this worked when I the lowest-level group name e.g. `matrix1_SiteName` which was the total value of the row.