# How to add a % column within an SSRS matrix group?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, reporting

I need some help with my SSRS matrix. Basically, I'm tracking our monthly permits based on whether they were created online or in-house. I would like to add a percentage column for quick reference. I've added this new % column within the matrix group:

[Image capture of my matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlNFy.jpg)

For reference, the IN-HOUSE / ONLINE column is [location]. Also, the values in the '# of Permits' columns is COUNT(PermitNumber).

I'm struggling with how to get the % values into this matrix. Any help or guidance is much appreciated. Thank you, everyone!

Comment: see below post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557705/calculate-percentage-of-total-columns-based-on-total-column-in-ssrs-matrix

Comment: yep looks like that's going to work. i have to get the expression correct for the total row, but it's working great for the individual month rows. thanks vik

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate percentage of total columns based on total column in SSRS Matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7557705/calculate-percentage-of-total-columns-based-on-total-column-in-ssrs-matrix)

Answer (score 0):

You need expressions like those below.

Change the group/dataset names inside the quotes to match your own month/year/dataset name

For month:

```
=COUNT(Fields!permits.Value) / COUNT(Fields!permits.Value, "month")
```

For year:

```
=COUNT(Fields!permits.Value) / COUNT(Fields!permits.Value, "year")
```

For total:

```
=COUNT(Fields!permits.Value) / COUNT(Fields!permits.Value, "DataSet1")
```